# without build app in Xcode 5 approve my ios app by Apple?

Tags: ios, ios7, app-store-connect

I want to upload my application in the iTunes store, currently I built my application in Xcode 4.6.1. after successfully built in the development. now I want to upload app.

but before upload I have two questions:

1. without IOS 7 compatable I can upload app in the iTunes store?
2. if an upload successful then Apple rejects my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No to both. Apps submitted to the app store MUST be made with Xcode 5 for iOS 7.